# Android how to sort list of objects in list view by column

Tags: android, sorting, android-listview

I bind list of class objects using adapters  in android list view, the list view have 3 column headers(3 header buttons), each header have click event, now i want to sort list view by column means when ever i click on first header column, the data sorted with respect to first column, i click second header sorted the data with respect to second column.How can i do this one.

Comment: please can any one answer to this question

Answer (score 2):

Loads of pseudo code ahead, you've been warned.

Say you have a class Foo

```
class Foo{

private int param1;
private float param2;
private String param3;
}
```

Now make 3 Comparators, one for each member you want to sort with. Preferably make it a static member of the same class.

```
class Foo
{
  public static Comparator PARAM1_COMPARATOR = <defination>;
  public static Comparator PARAM2_COMPARATOR = <defination>;
  public static Comparator PARAM3_COMPARATOR = <defination>;
}
```

In your activity, have this function `refreshList()` (or something of that sort ) which is called when the sorting order is to be changed.

```
void refreshList()
{
  List<Foo> list = //say this is your list

  //Pro tip: User a switch case instead.

  if(Sort_by_param1)
   Collections.sort(list, Foo.PARAM1_COMPARATOR);
  if(Sort_by_param2)
   Collections.sort(list, Foo.PARAM2_COMPARATOR);
  if(Sort_by_param3)
   Collections.sort(list, Foo.PARAM3_COMPARATOR);

  adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() or call setAdapter again with the new list.
}
```

Comment: I declare Comparator in same Foo class but in my Activity i didn't get Foo.PARAM1_COMPARATOR.

Comment: Change access mode of Foo as default to public, if Foo and your Activity both are in different packages.

Comment: Both are same package and i declared Foo as Public but i didn't get that one

Comment: Hi, I hope I can get an answer after 2 years of reply. This solution is the one that i was looking for but I didn't understand the <defination> part, what should I write there? I looked for many sources but couldn't find any answer

Comment: Hi @Onur, In the definition, I meant the implementation of the Comparator.

Comment: Wow, this is fast. But I don't know how to implement a Comparator and couldn't find and example like you did. Could you please enlighten me?

Answer (score 2):

Follow this code to sort any ArrayList

```
  Collections.sort(empList, new Comparator<Employee>(){
  public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2) {
    return emp1.getFirstName().compareToIgnoreCase(emp2.getFirstName());
  }
});
```